# set up UITouch's moving range

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch-event

I create a touch moving event for a label which size is (30, 50). here is the code

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UIView *superView = self.superview;
}
```

But I need to make sure the label can only move inside the superview. In other word, UILabel will stop moving when it “touch” the edge of view, How to setup label's moving range?

Comment: You want to move the label to the position of the touch?

Comment: What have you tried until now? Can you add it to you question? I think you might have to treat the moving in `touchesMoved` method.

Comment: @UlyssesR what I need is making the uilabel can't move when it touches the edge of its superview.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the label to your touch position
2. Check whether the label's frame is inside of the superView
3. If it is outside,change the frame,and set `userInteractionEnabled` to NO

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.center = [touches.anyObject locationInView:self.superview];

    CGRect bounds = self.superview.bounds;
    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;

    if (newFrame.origin.x < 0) {
        newFrame.origin.x = 0;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    if (newFrame.origin.y<0) {
        newFrame.origin.y = 0;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    if (newFrame.origin.x + newFrame.size.width > bounds.size.width) {
        newFrame.origin.x = bounds.size.width - newFrame.size.width;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    if (newFrame.origin.y + newFrame.size.height > bounds.size.height) {
        newFrame.origin.y = bounds.size.height - newFrame.size.height;
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }

    self.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I need is the label can't move when it will be outside. With your the label will be back after moving end. In other word, when label.origin.x or y < 0, how can I disable moving?

Comment: You can see the UIView's property `userInteractionEnabled`

> default is YES. if set to NO, user events (touch, keys) are ignored and removed from the event queue.So you can set the `userInteractionEnabled` to NO when the label.frame is outside of it's superView.

Comment: userInteractionEnabled still doesn't work. it won't stop even the uilabel is outside untill I stop tap on it.